# Docker command is unable to find my configuration file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker command is unable to find my configuration file

I have a **pm2** Docker image for launching nodeJS process in production. The image can be found here: https://hub.docker.com/r/keymetrics/pm2/~/dockerfile/

Docker launch the command `pm2-runtime start pm2.json` and fails as it can't find any `/pm2.json`.

However I do have a `pm2.json` in the working directory, so why is it looking at the root `/` ?

I would also like to run the docker images with docker-compose. Is there something to configure in the docker-compose.yml file to look at the working directory ?

Answer (score 0):

When I check the official [Dockerfile](https://github.com/keymetrics/docker-pm2/blob/master/example-app/Dockerfile):

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:{{tag}}

# Bundle APP files
COPY src src/
COPY package.json .
COPY pm2.json .

# Install app dependencies
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
RUN npm install --production

# Show current folder structure in logs
RUN ls -al -R

CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "pm2.json" ]
```

It is copying the `npm2.json` from the [directory](https://github.com/keymetrics/docker-pm2/tree/master/example-app) inside the image.
Aren't you missing that part?

Answer (score 0):

The default working directory for running binaries within a container is the root directory (/).

If you want to change it:

1. Using `docker run`: `docker run -w="..."`
2. Using docker-compose: `working_dir` is what you need, see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir